# How do I instantiate a moving GameObject directly above another one without messing up the anchoring in ARCore?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am creating a mobile application based on the game called StackAR on android for my university. It is essentially a game where you can stack cubes above each other, the more you stack, the higher the score.

[This is it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyWJ9cw4mn8), I am recreating this.

Now what I am doing is on screen press, an anchor is set to the trackable and an empty GO with a cube as a child gets instantiated. So now the prefab is set to the anchor. In turn that outputs on the mobile screen a cube placed on the plane.

For the problem...
When I want to add a moving cube on top the other one (Just like in the video above), the cube is offset from the anchor point for no reason.

The empty GameObject on the scene is being filled with the cubes when the user touches, and then being parented to the anchor and the empty GO. And the funny thing is, whenever I add them manually from the hierarchy, the output comes out exactly how I want it.

Here is the function that adds the cube to the tower or stack.

```
 private void AddToStack()
    {


        GameObject nextInStack = Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(hit.Pose.position.x, hit.Pose.position.y + (numberOfObjects * yOffset.y * 2), hit.Pose.position.z), hit.Pose.rotation);

        nextInStack.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Tower").transform;

        nextInStack.transform.localPosition = anchor.transform.position;

        listOfCubes.Add(nextInStack);
    }
```

And this that adds the initial empty GO.

```
    private void PlaceBase()
    {
        GameObject placed_obj = Instantiate(gameobj_to_place, new Vector3(hit.Pose.position.x, hit.Pose.position.y + yOffset.y, hit.Pose.position.z), hit.Pose.rotation);

        anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

        placed_obj.transform.parent = anchor.transform;

        baseCubeIsPlaced = true;

        //AddToStack();

    }
```

And this is present on the script called CubeBehaviour that is responsible for moving the cube left to right.

```
        private void TranslateCubeForward()
    {
        forwardMethod = true;

        if (isGoingForward)
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        else
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.localPosition.z >= limitOfTranslation)
        {
            isGoingForward = false;
        }

        if (transform.localPosition.z <= -limitOfTranslation)
        {
            isGoingForward = true;
        }

    }
```

I expected the cube would be placed right above the other one when moving. But when the object is moving the entire thing is offset, when the script from movement is removed from the cube, it is instantiated correctly.